# Puppet - Notify a class with parameters

Tags: puppet

I'm pretty new to puppet, and I've got stuck on how to notify a class with a parameter. I'm trying to notify a class that I found, which runs update-rc.d with a parameter:

```
define myclass::update-rc {
    exec { "update-rc_${title}":
        command => "update-rc.d ${title} defaults",
        cwd => "/tmp",
        path => "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:",
        refreshonly => true
    }
}
```

And the class that I wish to notify it from:

```
class mysecondclass {
    file { '/etc/init.d/myscript':
        ensure => file,
        notify => Class['myclass::update-rc { "myscript": } ']
    }
}
```

It fails with the error:

`Could not find dependent Exec[Myclass::update-rc { "myscript": } ] ...`

It does work if I just put `myclass::update-rc { "myscript": }` in the class like this:

```
class mysecondclass {
    file { '/etc/init.d/myscript':
        ensure => file,
    }

    myclass::update-rc { "myscript": }
}
```

But I kinda wanted to notify it ... Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: you are trying to call a define as a class, it isn't a class. It looks like there will only ever be one instance of it so change it to a class instead.

Comment: why not place the file in /etc/init.d then manage it with the service resource instead of a defined type? `service { 'name_of_service': enable => true }` should handle the `update-rc.d` command i believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notify a class several ways in puppet:

- with notify/subscribe https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#syntax-relationship-metaparameters
- with chaining arrows https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#syntax-chaining-arrows

With subscribe you will need to update the exec from inside update-rc define:

```
exec { "update-rc_${title}":
  command     => "update-rc.d ${title} defaults",
  cwd         => "/tmp",
  path        => "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:",
  refreshonly => true,
  subscribe   => File['/etc/init.d/myscript'],
}
```

With notify you will need to update file resource:

```
myclass::update-rc { "myscript": }

file { '/etc/init.d/myscript':
  ensure => file,
  notify => Myclass::Update-rc["myscript"]
}
```

This is equivalent, but using chaining arrows:

```
file { '/etc/init.d/myscript':
  ensure => file,
} ~>
myclass::update-rc { "myscript": }
```

Pay attention that it's a tilde there and not a normal arrow.

Also, you should update your define name from update-rc to update_rc: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_reserved.html#classes-and-defined-types

Comment: I was hoping to be able to leave the update-rc class alone, and and call it when needed (or in this case, notify it) ... Your solution doesn't take into account that ${title} is only set when the myclsss::update-rc is called in the way that I have shown at the bottom of my question ...

Comment: O, sorry about that, I didn't noticed you use $title. I will update my answer

Comment: Yeah I still don't think you understand what I mean Lol ... If I put `myclass::update-rc.d { 'myscript': }` in `mysecondclass`, it runs `update-rc.d myscript defaults` ... I want to be able to do that with a `notify =>` ... I don't want to change the `myclass::update-rc.d`, because I want it re-usable.

Comment: Phew, got there in the end! Thanks a lot :D ... It seems it was the chaining I was after, which I didn't know anything about Lol (I've only been using puppet for the last week or so) ... That's going to make my life a whole lot easier! ... I found some documentation that explains the different chaining arrows here too - https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#syntax-chaining-arrows

Comment: If you want to edit your answer, explaining just the chaining, I'm sure it will help out some other Puppet noob Lol, and I'll accept it :D